# How to prevent Winform popup box CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe Breakpoint A has been reached?

Tags: .net, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I include CefSharp 73 using nuget in my Winforms C# 4.5.2 application. Occasionally a message box pops up with the title *CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe* and the content *Breakpoint A breakpoint has been reached*. What should I do to prevent this message from popping?

I'm updating my winforms app from CEF 55 to CEF 73. I tried to get CefSharp crash dumps by adding `crash_reporter.cfg` file to the working folder of my executable, but I didn't get any dump files. Also, there are no error messages in `debug.log`.

Comment: To confirm that you've enabled crash reporting correctly you can force a crash, see step three in https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/CrashReporting.md#markdown-header-testing Sounds like you are hitting an assertion in CEF/Chromium.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I did use the 3 crash causing URLs per cef wiki, but didn't get any crash reports files on the PC where I'm running CefSharp. The wiki page suggests creating a local server using Python to receive crash reports. I'm not familiar with Python, so it will not be easy for me to setup it up. Is there a way to get the crash reports in local files?

Comment: You can create dumps on disk without a server, have a read of the whole wiki page in detail.

Comment: Found crash report in C:\Users\[CurrentUser]\AppData\Local\[AppName]\User Data.
Had to dig through comments in the source code.

Comment: It's stated in the config section of the wiki.

Comment: Did you ever find the root of the probem, or how to fix it?

Comment: @SorinBolos, I don't recall this was resolved, but it went away somehow. Could have been a Windows update that solved it.